# Crop image from uInt8List Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, crop

i an developing an tool for publish image like instagram,

[image]

the problem is that i want to cut the image and send to server square, my problem is that t can not cut the image sqaure from the original image, i have a uInt8List from my image.

how can i cut my image?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an extension on Face from Firebase's Vision Api, it returns you the image bytes data which you can just plug into your Image.memory widget.
Forget to mention you need the image library :
    - https://pub.dev/packages/image

```
extension FaceExtension on Face {
 Future<Uint8List> getFaceFromImage(File imageFile) async {
    final image = await imageFile.readAsBytes();
    final decodedImage = decodeImage(image);

    final rectangle = this.boundingBox;

    final face = copyCrop(
      decodedImage,
      rectangle.topLeft.dx.toInt(),
      rectangle.topLeft.dy.toInt(),
      rectangle.width.toInt(),
      rectangle.height.toInt(),
    );

    return Uint8List.fromList(encodePng(face));
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this package requires google_mlkit_face_detection ?